# OkHttpClient in android

Tags: android

I wrote the following code to send a request to the server and getting the response from server. But When I run the following code It can not work for me. I wrote this code based [this link](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/06/okhttp-2.html).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity);
       Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bu1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    run();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/file.php")
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        Response response = call.execute();

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }
        String text = response.body().string();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the error. please post some logcat.

Comment: What is not working for you? Please show us the error

Comment: you have internet permission?-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the error is because:

1. Doesn't have Internet Permission
2. It is in UI thread

You can confirm it in the logcat.

Solution:

1. Add in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
2. You must run in other thread or using the async one like this:

   ```
   public void run() {
       Request request = new Request.Builder()
               .url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/file.php")
               .build();

       Call call = client.newCall(request);
       call.enqueue(new Callback() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
               Log.d("TAG", "Failed: " + e.getMessage());
           }

           @Override
           public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
               Log.d("TAG", "OK: " + response.body().string());
           }
       }
   }
   ```